# Spring aop and aspectj

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, aspects

How to store all the logged method calls in database of a single session using spring aop and aspectj ?

In the following code i will get the method names i need to capture them and store in database for an individual session.

```
@Aspect
    @Component
    public class LoggingAspect {

    //  @Autowired
    //  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    //  
    //  @Autowired
    //  private ActionRolesService actionRolesService;


       private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

       @Pointcut(" execution(java.lang.String com.bis.sourcelead.entity..*.*()) && "
               + "!execution(java.lang.String com.bis.sourcelead.entity..*.set*()) && "
               + "!execution(java.lang.String com.bis.sourcelead.entity..*.get*())")
       private void intercepterMethod() {
       }

       @Pointcut("execution(@javax.inject.Inject * com.bis.sourcelead.web..*.*(..))")
       public void methodAnnotatedWithInjectAndInDemoPackage() {

       }

       @Before("intercepterMethod()")
       public void logAround(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
           logger.info("********** Action class Before Method Excution ************");
           logger.info("Class name : " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName());
           logger.info("Method name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
           logger.info("Parameters name : " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));

       }

       @Before("execution(* com.bis.sourcelead.service..*.*(..))")
       public void logBeforeService(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
           logger.info("**********Service Layer Before Method Excution ************");
           logger.info("Class name : " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName());
           logger.info("Method name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
           logger.info("Parameters name : " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));

       }

       @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.bis.sourcelead.service..*.*(..))", returning = "result")
       public void logAfterReturningService(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
           logger.info("********** Service Layer After Method Exectution ************");
           logger.info("Class name : " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName());
           logger.info("Method name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
           logger.info("Method returned value  : " + result);
       }

       @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.bis.sourcelead.service.*.*(..))", throwing = "error")
       public void logAfterThrowingService(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) {
           logger.info("********** Service Layer Method Throwing Error ************");
           logger.info("Class name : " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName());
           logger.error("Method name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
           logger.error("Exception : " + error);

       }

       @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.bis.sourcelead.dao.*.*(..))", throwing = "error")
       public void logAfterThrowingDao(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) {
           logger.info("********** Dao Layer Method Throwing Error ************");
           logger.info("Class name : " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName());
           logger.error("Method name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
           logger.error("Exception : " + error);

       }

       @Around("execution(* com.bis.sourcelead.dao..*.*(..))")
       public Object logAroundDao(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
           Object result = null;
           logger.info("********** Dao Layer Before Method Excution ************");
           logger.info("Class name : " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName());
           logger.info("Method name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
           logger.info("Parameters name : " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));

           long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
           //result = joinPoint.proceed(); //continue on the intercepted method
           result = joinPoint.proceed(joinPoint.getArgs()); //continue on the intercepted method
           long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
           logger.info("********** Dao Layer After Method Excution ************");
           logger.info("Method execution time: " + elapsedTime + " milliseconds.");

           return result;
       }

       @Before("execution(* com.bis.sourcelead.rest..*.*(..)) && methodAnnotatedWithInjectAndInDemoPackage() ")
       public void logBeforeWebService(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
           logger.info("**********Web Service Layer Before Method Excution ************");
           logger.info("Class name : " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName());
           logger.info("Method name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
           logger.info("Parameters name : " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));

           System.out.print("Executed the @Injected method: "
                   + joinPoint.getSignature() + " with value(s): ");

           for (Object object : joinPoint.getArgs()) {
               System.out.print(object);
           }
           System.out.println();

       }


       @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.bis.sourcelead.rest..*.*(..))", returning = "result")
       public void logAfterReturningWebService(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
           logger.info("********** Web Service Layer After Method Exectution ************");
           logger.info("Class name : " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName());
           logger.info("Method name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
           logger.info("Method returned value  : " + result);


    //       try {
    //         if(joinPoint.getSignature().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("createUser"))
    //             logger.info("pradeep::"+actionRolesService.getActionNameUsingMethodName(joinPoint.getSignature().getName()));
    //  } catch (Exception e) {
    //      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //      e.printStackTrace();
    //  }

        }

       @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.bis.sourcelead.rest.*.*(..))", throwing = "error")
       public void logAfterThrowingWebService(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) {
           logger.info("********** Web Service Layer Method Throwing Error ************");
           logger.info("Class name : " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName());
           logger.error("Method name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
           logger.error("Exception : " + error);

       }


    }
    //end class
```

Comment: Why would that be any different then storing something in the DB as you would do in regular java?

Comment: I am having a logging aspect class which is having some pointcuts and i need to save the methods only which are being called at that pointcut. @M.Deinum

Comment: Again why would that be any different then regular java. You are writing Java, you are already logging the information. Just write JDBC instead calling your logging framework.

Comment: when i am trying to add the jdbc code in my aspect class my aspect class is not getting called . @M.Deinum

Comment: Then put that in your question as that makes your question a different one. Then also include the code that isn't doing/working as you expected it to work.

Comment: thank you , its working fine now . @M.Deinum

Comment: need a java class which creates a session and stores all the user actions in database based on session and used id . @M.Deinum